# Iterate array, modify and insert other elements

Tags: ruby

I want to iterate an array, modify its element based on one criteria and want to insert another element after each element, except after the last. What would be the most Ruby-idiomatic way to do so?

```
def transform(input)
  words = input.split
  words.collect {|w|
    if w == "case1"
      "add that"
    else
      "add these" + w
    end
    # plus insert "x" after every element, but not after the last
  }
end
```

Example:

```
transform("Hello case1 world!") => ["add theseHello", "x", "add that", "x", "add theseworld!"]
```

Comment: I'd probably create a new collection.

Comment: As always, sample input and sample output is *required.*  It's too easy to be ambiguous in English. For example, is there an "x" after *every* element?  Really?  Because you might have meant, "only after every new element that was added". Is the original element kept?

Comment: @DigitalRoss You are absolutely right, my bad! Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making some assumptions about desired output, and editting:

```
def transform(input)
  input.split.inject([]) do |ar, w|
    ar << (w == "case1" ? "add that" : "add these" + w) << "x"
  end[0..-2]
end

p transform("Hello case1 world!")

#=> ["add theseHello", "x", "add that", "x", "add theseworld!"]
```

Comment: That looks good so far, but I would like to have the result as an array and not a string: ["add", " ", "these", " " ...]

Comment: Then @DigitalRoss' answer suits you better.

Comment: Editted to meet desired output.

Comment: @Mel Nicholson: It doesn't fail: `[][0..-2] # => []`

Answer (score 0):

```
def transform input
  input.split.map do |w|
    [
      if w == 'case1'
        'add that'
      else
        'add these' + w
      end,
      'x'
    ]
  end.flatten[0..-2]
end
```

This would often be written as:

```
def transform input
  input.split.map do |w|
    [ w == 'case1' ? 'add that' : 'add these' + w, 'x' ]
  end.flatten[0..-2]
end
```

Comment: prefer [`flat_map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) over `map{...}.flatten`